# How to convert String Datetime to timestamp in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I want to convert this string `datetimestring = 'Fri, 08 Jun 2012 22:40:26 GMT'` to timestamp using python.

I tried

```
 timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(datetimestring, '%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))
```

but reports regex error.

Comment: Don't just tell us you got an error, give us the actual error.

Comment: Especially because there is no regex in the code you pasted :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `%B`, which corresponds to the full month name, but you only have the abbreviated name.  You should use `%b` instead:

```
>>> import time
>>> datetimestring = 'Fri, 08 Jun 2012 22:40:26 GMT' 
>>> timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(datetimestring, '%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 454, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Fri, 08 Jun 2012 22:40:26 GMT' does not match format '%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'
>>> timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(datetimestring, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))
>>> timestamp
1339209626.0
```

Answer (score 4):

import time
import dateutil.parser as dateparser

```
datetimestring = 'Fri, 08 Jun 2012 22:40:26 GMT'
dt = dateparser.parse(datetimestring)
timestamp = int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
```

Comment: This solution converts different string date formats, so you don't care about the formatting.

Comment: This solution works great! 

But, i think needed to install this:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser

Comment: I think this is better solution because it is not need specified  format of date, vote up

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dateparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser) for this purpose.

`import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('Fri, 08 Jun 2012 22:40:26 GMT')
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 8, 22, 40, 26)`