# Getting local timestamp from the server timestamp

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

```
below is the Scenario:

 1. (Host-machine)User will create tasks on the server by sending task information to the rest services of server (task_name,task_owner etc)
 2. (server-machine)server will receive information from the user and creates a timestamp(2017-08-07 08:42:07-04:00) along with timezone for the task and saves into a database
 3. user will do list tasks and user must be able to see task_name,task_owner and task_creation time

Assuming Host-machine and server-machine are on different timezones.

when user does list tasks we trigger the rest-services and processes the tasks timestamps and show local timestamps equivalent to server timezone.
```

my Host-machine code is using python to trigger rest-services and parsing the result..

```
 so,

    input: 2017-08-07 08:42:07-04:00
    output : 2017-08-07 17:30:03
    explanation: its converting from time stamp of one time zone to                              
                 another timezone.EDT is 2017-08-07 08:42:07-04:00 
                 IST is 2017-08-07 08:42:07+5:30 .
                 so, assume Local is IST the time must be ~17:30 
                 (8:42:07+9:30)
```

New Bee to python Help me out :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert String Datetime to timestamp in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957522/how-to-convert-string-datetime-to-timestamp-in-python)

Comment: @ThomasMey Thats not a duplicate!. as the post you shared is converting the String to Timestamp object of same time+offset. but my question is converting from time stamp of one time zone to another timezone.                 
  EDT is 2017-08-07 08:42:07-04:00                                                          
  IST is 2017-08-07 08:42:07+5:30 .Lets say Local is IST the time must be  ~9:30 (8:42:07+9:30). is there any such method in python to acheive this use case?

Comment: Any-one knows the Answer do reply.. That would be great!!.                              Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check our the docs for `datetime` and scroll to 8.1.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html 

There you find information how to parse your string.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will help you make things simpler in what you're trying to do. All dates and times on the server should be in UTC with the correct timezone saved for each user. Using `arrow` you can simply use:

```
import arrow

time = arrow.get(input_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ')

print time.to('local')
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.They will be in UTC in the database,but we are querying the database using the rest services on the host machine. the timestamps will be changed to local time zones of host machine. so, eventually the server will return the timestamps with the host time zones.so the value can be any timezone   
    FYI mysql does the same way it stores timestamp in UTC and when fetching the results it will modify the timestamps to the machine's time zones from where the database is queried which could be the expected behaviour. Let me know if i went wrong

Comment: I don't really understand your recent comment, nor do I understand if I actually solved your dilemma or not :)

Answer (score -1):

```
fixed this using the package called **tzlocal**



     def convert_date_format(self, server_time):
                local_date =parse(server_time).astimezone(get_localzone())
                return str(local_date.replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=None))

 **explanation**

input:  "2017-08-08 15:35:27-4:00"

   1.function takes server_time as input converts to datetime object using 
    parse()           
   2.get_localzone() will fetch the local time zone                                   
   3.using the astimezone() converted the server_time to local timestamp     
   4.removed the microseconds and timezone fields
```

Comment: how is that easier than using just `arrow.get(input).to('local')`?

Comment: @droravr its not easier,both are similar i am already using tzlocal for couple of things for timezone challenges. i dont want to use another package(arrow) as i am already using tzlocal which serves my purpose.